# How to Reload or Refresh Whole Screen Automatically When user enter in that screen. in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I want To refresh or reload whole screen automatically. when user enter in that screen. Then screen will instantly reload or refresh automatically. So how to do that in react native. is possible . if yes please help.

if I write That logic in componentDidMount Will it reload screen. if yes then How to write that in componentDidMount below.

```
  componentDidMount () {

    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',()=> this.handleBackButtonClick(), false);
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An often-used hack in React is to change the key prop of your component to force a re-mount of a view:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';


class APP extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  state = {
    uniqueValue: 1;
  }

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.forceRemount();
    return true;
}
  forceRemount = () => {
    this.setState({uniqueValue: this.state.uniqueValue + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View key={this.state.uniqueValue}>
        <Button onPress={this.forceRemount} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeeeh But How do I use It in My componentDidMounnt above code

Comment: I want to call It on hardware back button press is it possibble

Comment: this is coming= ')' expected.ts(1005).  at end semicolon of this  uniqueValue: uniqueValue + 1
    });

Comment: @SohilShaikh check now

Comment: Is there any way To check that is it really refreshing screen or not

Comment: @SohilShaikh you can check on the console is repeating or not

Comment: what repeating or not